# JDBC error in resultset.getsrting column position out of range for my code

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote this code to make a graphical user interface to deal database via Java, but I face some errors. I am searching and trying to fix it but still have the same errors.

```
private void DeleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    String sql1=("Delete From Mory.Boats Where DATE_OF_TRIP='?' and BOAT_NAME='?'"); 

    try {
                myconobj=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/New_Idea","Mory","Mory");
                PreparedStatement ps = myconobj.prepareStatement(sql1);
                ps.setString(1,Date_of_TripDateChooser.getDateFormatString());
                ps.setString(2,Boat_NameTextField.getText());

                mystmobj=myconobj.createStatement();
                mystmobj.toString();
                mystmobj.execute(sql1);

                ((DefaultTableModel)Boats1.getModel()).removeRow(Boats1.getSelectedRow());
                ps.execute();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");    

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }              
}                                            

}
```

It gives me column 1 out of range .
any help to fix this error

Comment: You aren't callng `ResultSet.getString()` in this code. There aren't any `ResultSets`at all.

Comment: And don't show 'deleted' unless something *was* deleted. The return value of `executeStatement()` tells you how many rows were affected, or `getUpdateCount()`. Unclear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the quotes around the question mark, `'?'` to just `?`. And do check out the Prepared Statement [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Also, these lines don't make sense. They are executing the query again and can be removed.

```
 mystmobj=myconobj.createStatement();
 mystmobj.toString();
 mystmobj.execute(sql1);
```

Comment: the error changed to (at least one parameter uninitialized)

Comment: Why do you have these lines? ` mystmobj=myconobj.createStatement();                mystmobj.toString(); mystmobj.execute(sql1);` when you also have the prepared statement? Remove those.